# In python, how could I import another file that was written part of another venv?

Tags: python, python-venv

I have a small scale front end web application (written in flask/python) that uses a back end (written in python).

Right now, I was using os.popen() to use the back end's CLI. But there is noticeable delays due to the many import the back end requires. I figure I could simply import the back end's python file in my flask app which is a wsgi service, and do the function call I need directly instead of using the CLI, thus only spending time on the import when restarting the service.

The problem is that the back end was made in a venv, whereas the flask app uses the system's python default env. When I import the backend, it complains that some of the modules the back end imports are missing (which is true because they were only installed in its venv).

I could install all the dependencies in my system default venv, but is there an alternative? Can I opt-in a venv at runtime (probably not but hey, I'm asking)?

Comment: A venv is nothing else then isolated Python with isolated libs. Just install missing libs, ensure that there are no conflicts with your front end server and you might be ok. Depending on what the imported module actually does. Because it is odd that you have a Python lib that you need to run via popen to begin with. Sounds like some hackish things going on under the hood. Unless it is a bad/legacy code.

Comment: The alternative is to install everything in its own venv not in the system env. Then do change the web front-end to use the imported code (back end) instead of calling the cli front.end via processes. That is why it is slow like you said.